# Ruby: Method to check for false

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a value is `false` on `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean`

I am using [sablon](https://github.com/senny/sablon) for template processing and it currently supports truthy expression and [else](https://github.com/senny/sablon/issues/11) is not supported currently.

I can only call a method on context object, so is there any **method** something like `obj.false?`

Please don't suggest `!` or `unless` as I am restricted to using a method on the context object.

Comment: elaborate, please

Comment: Can you please give an example and explain why you don't want to use common Ruby idioms like `!` or `unless`?

Comment: `instance_of? FalseClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
object.!
```

`!` is a method on the object.

In Ruby `!` is not an operator but a method call.

Comment: ...but `nil.! #=> true`. Am I missing something? I wasn't aware of  [BasicObject#!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-21).